# How to make nested loop into recursive function?

Tags: java

Is it possible to convert multiple nested for loop structure as following to a recursive function?

```
void printHierarchy()
{ 
  for(int i=1;i<4;i++)
  {
      System.out.println(i);
      for(int j=1;j<4;j++)
      {
          System.out.println(i + "-" + j);
          for(int k=1;k<4;k++)
          {
              System.out.println(i + "-" + j + "-" + k);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I am struggling with entry criteria and exit criteria for this code. And further challenge is printing the i-j-k values as these will not be recorded in recursive function call.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question looks like a homework question, so I'm going to link to "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)", but otherwise it seems to be a reasonable question.

Comment: @Haem This is not a homework question, I am currently working on similar nested loop code. I have to make it so that the loops are infinitely scalable on hierarchy level (ex: i-j-k-l-n and so on..) without adding additional for loops. So my approach was to make it recursive, but I am struggling to convert the code as mentioned, hence this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would modify `Haem's` version as follows to use a private method to help control both depth and limit.  The meanings of depth and limit are subjective and could be modified to reflect intent.

```java
   public static void recursivePrintHierarchy(String prefix, int depth) {
      __recursivePrintHierarchy(prefix, depth - 1, depth);
   }

   private static void __recursivePrintHierarchy(String prefix, int depth, int limit) {
      if (depth < 0) {
         return;
      }
      for (int i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
         String result = prefix + i;
         System.out.println(result);
         __recursivePrintHierarchy(result + "-", depth - 1, limit);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

With nested loops, you'd usually take the depth of nesting, and exit when the depth is less than zero. Here, I'm calling a single loop non-nested. You probably won't want to write that loop out as recursive. The initial call to the method would be the intended depth of nesting.

As for the `i`,`j` and `k` from the outer loop, you'd need some sort of a data structure to pass these to the next recursion. In this case, the easiest way would be to use a `String`, namely what you're prefixing to the current hierarchy level. The initial value for this would be an empty `String`.

Put together, here's the code:

```java
void recursivePrintHierarchy(String prefix, int depth){
  if(depth<0){
    return
  }
  for(int i=1;i<4;i++){
    String result=prefix+i;
    System.out.println(result);
    recursivePrintHierarchy(result+"-", depth-1);
  }
}
```

Comment: This was my initial approach, but the problem with this is that you cannot determine on which level you are currently on, you can only go 1, 1-1, 1-1-1 then come out of loop and start at 2, 2-1, 2-1-1. The hierarchy branch 1-2, 1-2-1 will not get printed.

Comment: @mightyOne I was missing an `i++` in my code, but with that added my code seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If we leave out the hyphen `-` for a moment you are just printing the string representations of a subset of base 4 numbers. All base 4 numbers would be `[0000, 0001 ..., 3333]` and your subset is `[0100, 0101, ... 0333]`. So if you remove each `0`, filter duplicates and keep only those which have a length `>=1 && <= 3` you will get your desierd values `[1,11,111,112,113,12,121,...,333]` where you need only to insert your hyphen inbetween.

So you could simply do something like:

```
static void printHierarchy(int depth) {
    int base = depth + 1;      
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.pow(base, base); i++) {
        list.add(Integer.toString(i, base));          
    }
    list.stream()
            .map(s -> s.replace("0", ""))     
            .filter(s -> s.length() < base)   
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())        
            .distinct()                       
            .map(s -> String.join("-", s.split("")))  
            .sorted()                                 
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Note: This is a very slow algorithm and because the size of combinations grows exponentaly I would use it if your depth is small (i.e <= 7). Tested for depth from 1 - 9. Works till depth = 7 good on my machine.

The exponential growth of your combinations depending on depth

```
1 : 1
2 : 6
3 : 39
4 : 340
5 : 3905
6 : 55986
7 : 960799
8 : 19173960
```